# android : gridview how to specify layout params when viewholder is used

Tags: android, gridview

In my gridview i want to display some text on top of each image. So in the xml i have defined a relative layout with one image view and a text view.

In the getview method of adapter i am using a view holder with one image view and one text view. Now my question is how to set layout params.

code

```
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.griditems, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.text1 = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
```

........

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView text1;
    ImageView image;

}
```

the xml is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/GridItem" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:padding="15dip"
>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY">
</ImageView>
<TextView android:id="@+id/grid_item_text"
    android:layout_width="200dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/labelbg"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/grid_item_image"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>
```

if i try holder.image.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200,
             200)); its giving exception . How to set this. Is there an option to set it in xml file using some general kes like fill_parent

Answer (score 0):

In your Gridview adapter , in getView method , use the fallowing :

```
   View v;
   LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
   v = li.inflate(R.layout.griditems, null);


    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
    tv.setText("image number" + position);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap); // what image you want

    return v;
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. My question is not about setting the image source, but defining the size of grid using layout params. If it was just an image view i can define it using .image.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200).. but here i am using a view holder.

Comment: i don't understand why do you need an image holder ... for your task a gridview with images with texts above it's enough what i have proposed... you can arange the picture and text in the view from the xml file

Comment: i need text over the image , not above. Its like the text embedded in the image. I hope i am clear

Comment: really sorry for the confusion . That was the need for defining a relative layout and using view holder